# How should I think about implement the closing of an open equity position in my portfolio app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, ruby-on-rails-5, software-design

I have a model `PortStock` that has a schema that looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: port_stocks
#
#  id                :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  portfolio_id      :integer
#  stock_id          :integer
#  volume            :integer
#  transaction_price :float
#  current_price     :float
#  percent_change    :float
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  current_value     :float
#  dollar_change     :float
#  total_spend       :float
#  transaction_date  :datetime
#  action            :integer
#  position          :integer          default("open")
#  ticker            :string
#  slug              :string
#
```

When someone buys a stock, the app creates a `port_stock` that has `position: "open", action: :buy` in their `portfolio`.

When they `sell` that position, essentially what happens is they create another `port_stock` but it just has `position: "closed", action: :sell`.

I have a few questions:

1. Is that really the most optimal structure? One immediate issue I see with this is that I have to `close` the `buy` position. So in essence, the full `completed position` would be two `closed`  `buy` and `sell` `port_stock` records. If there is only one, then the position is considered open. But does that make sense?
2. Should I create a method in my model to both close and open positions? I originally did this just in my controllers, but now that I am writing unit tests I don't have a clean way to close an existing open position.

Should I be approaching the buying & selling of `port_stock` differently?

Thoughts?

Comment: i think it's better to maintain a single instance and update the `position` based on the action and to maintain `position_bought_date` & `position_sold_date` so, that it is easy to maintain & validate it.

Comment: @uday well I need to track every transaction, both buying and selling. For example, say you bought 100 shares of Acme Inc, and want to sell 20 shares later...you don't close out the entire thing, just 20 shares. So I need to record both the reduction of the 100 to 80 and the price, date & time, etc. of when the 20 were sold to reflect it in portfolio value. So I have to track it in two different transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to keep each transactions.

If you bought 100 shares of Acme, and want to sell 20 shares later; you have to keep the both transactions in your portfolio.

To find out how many actions you have, you have to sum the transactions for each action.
Maybe it's repetitive but it's the best option for follow the value of a portfolio.

For example, if you want compute your P&L you have to sum `(price*volume*spot_change)` for each transaction, if `action = sell` you multiply by `-1` else you multiply by `1`.

What is the final goal of your code ? Tell me if I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The question presents two different concepts. The first concept is a "position" and the second is a "transaction". A position is the number of shares that are actually owned. This number can be positive (long) for a stock that is owned or negative (short) for stock that you've sold but must buy back at some point in time.

The position will have one or more transactions against it. Each transaction will be open, executed, or closed with related attributes such as openedOn, executedOn, and possibly closedOn for transactions that were opened but never executed.

An open transaction might represent a bid to buy shares at a particular price. But if the offer is never executed and the user chooses to cancel that transaction you will still have a record of it even though it never resulted in the purchase of shares.

With this structure, the position object only keeps track of the summary information of all completed transactions and not the transaction information making it easier to track all of the transactions that were performed against a particular position, i.e., multiple buys to accumulate shares of a stock to build a position or multiple sells to trim a position.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is one concept which is missed . This makes your approach non-optimal. The equity transactions in real world also have Partial executions which are not handled here. 
   Partial executions can occur both during Buy and Sell.

> For eg. If you created a limit order to buy 1000 shares at 1 $. The only matching order the ROMS system (or whichever trade matching system you use) can find is for 500 shares.
>   In this case , you need to maintain a variable with 
>   quantity:500 , action : partial

Also , partial executions can happen during market order.

> For eg. You triggered a sale of 1000 shares at market price. The first 200 shares get sold at 1 $ , and remaining 800 shares at .8$. The action : close can only happen once the completed sale has taken place.

2. I agree that the method should be kept in the model for buying and selling.